# Zero probabilities in rb-libsvm

Tags: ruby, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I'm using rb-libsvm for prediction using

```
x.each_with_index do |e, i|
    predictions << model_w2v.predict_probability(e).to_i
end
```

Which returns an array where the first element is the label, and the second is the probabilities of all labels. E.g. `[2.0, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]`. The label is different each time, however the probabilities are always zeros. I wonder if it's because the numbers are too small and rounded to 0.0 when converting from c to ruby. Here's [the relevant c code](https://github.com/febeling/rb-libsvm/blob/bf76a0be268c41f17894a956e84cefb946d8a4c4/ext/libsvm/libsvm.c#L401):

```
estimates = rb_ary_new();
for (i = 0; i < model->nr_class; i++)
  rb_ary_push(estimates, rx_from_double(c_estimates[i]));
```

How can I mitigate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rb-libsvm` gem and the underlying `libsvm` require setting the probability param to true. Thus, I just had to add this line and re-train the model:

```
parameter.probability = 1
```

Where `parameter` was defined earlier as

```
parameter = Libsvm::SvmParameter.new
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11103619)

Comment: Actually that's the complete answer, I just had to add this line to get the probabilities.

Comment: Ok. On the first sight it didn't look like that. Maybe explaining a bit more would be helpful for other people searching for solution.

Comment: Edited, I hope it's better now.